# How to properly scale image in uv editor

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

Hello to anyone who come here and help out or read. I have an issue with the uv editor, I have been trying to make an proper eye. The issue is that I can't figure out how to scale this correctly.

[image]

Is there anything I can do to make the eye colors or texture?

[image]

[image]

Comment: That didn't work for me. I did your steps just now and it shows the same result as the images posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select just the front faces that correspond to the iris, and unwrap them from view and scale up/down to align with the colored portion of the image. The rest of the faces in your object mesh (ctrl-I for inverse selection) can then be unwrapped and scaled down to fit in just the white portion of your image. They then only get color info from that white area, and then your eye model will have workable mapping. If you then want a better uv map that has equal sides, you can bake from this uv mapped image to a new blank one using a second uv map.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the eye in the whole eyeball, so select only the faces that you want the image on.

In the case of a UV sphere it's easier to do this in top orhto view.

Then do project from view (bounds).

[image]

Use that UV map to map thimage on a material for the iris,
then assign a different material for the rest of the eye.

[image]

Note that the second material would not be necessary if the original image had an alpha channel filling the image around the iris instead of just white, then you could use the alpha to have better control on the placement of the texture.